# Stripe Rails Integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, runtime-error, stripe-payments

I've followed [this tutorial](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/guides/rails) to a T, copying and pasting all of the code 4 times and am still having issues loading the view for the demo payment.

This is my error

```
Missing template charges/new, application/new with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. 
Searched in:
* "~/projectdirectory/app/views"
* "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/devise-2.1.2/app/views"
```

I've looked everywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What files do you have in the directory `app/views/charges`?

There should be one named `new.html.erb`.  It appears to be missing.

Comment: ugh. I'm so foolish. I kept adding that view to the layouts folder. Sometimes staring at the same thing over and over, and checking it, you still can't see it for what it is! Thanks! Should I delete this question?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a view template at app/views/charges/new.html.erb or some other file there?

For a better answer, you should provide more info - i.e. what tutorial you're using.

-M